# Design a circle of items Android

Tags: java, android

I had to do something like this,but I have no idea where or how to start.
what's the name of this design ? I mean a circle with elements ?
and how to put a texteview with an angle of rotation ?

the goal is when I click in the circle the categories appears like the picture, so how I can do this animation ?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need some assets to create those ragged lines.

You can rotate `TextView`s with [setRotation()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setRotation(float)), calculating the rotation when inflating your view. To do so, you'll first have to determine the positions you want to put the text at and then calculate the angle by looking at the difference in `x` and `y` position from the center of the circle.

Edit: After OP specified the requirements in comments on this questions:

Inflate the view with all text elements 'hidden' (`android:visibility="gone"` in your xml file) and calculate the final rotations and positions for everything outside of the circle that you need to animate. Set a listener on the initial circle, which starts animations on all elements to change:

- their visibility to `View.VISIBLE`
- their position to what you've calculated
- their rotation to what you've calculated

For this, you'll likely want to use an [`AnimationSet`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/AnimationSet.html), look at [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6979792/androidtranslation-and-rotation-animation-simultaneously) for inspiration.

Comment: thank's, but I'll edit the post, I wasn't clear, the goal is to click in the circle to display the others categories like the picture, so how I can do this animation ??

Comment: What kind of animation are you talking about? Fade in, sliding out from the center of the circle, unfolding? Do you have an animation of the design?

Comment: the animation is like that : first, only the circle appears, but when I click the categories sliding out from the center of the circle, sorry for being not clear

Answer (score 1):

Ok what I understand from you question ..Initially you have circle like `1abc` in the figure.once you tab on the circle it should display the list of items in a circular way around the circle. ryt?

Step 1: Set the TextView's around Circle using

The fastest and most convenient way is to Rotate by Animation

use rotate animation on your regular TextView like so.

```
rotateAnimation.xml:

<rotate  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
           android:fromDegrees="0" 
           android:toDegrees="-90"
           android:pivotX="50%"
           android:duration="0"
           android:fillAfter="true" />
```

for sake of demo i have given `90` degree rotation you can give angle based on your requirement
    Java Code:

```
  TextView text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtview);       
  text.setText("rotated text here");

  RotateAnimation rotate= (RotateAnimation)AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,R.anim.rotateAnimation);
  text.setAnimation(rotate);
```

Do this for all your TextView's to place it proper position.

Step 2: After the design make them `Invisible` `yourTextView.setVisibility(View.Gone);`

Step 3: On touching the `Circle` make All the `TextView's` `Visible`

```
yourTextView.setVisibility(View.Visible);
```

Answer (score 0):

Following this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5262418/4170584) on SO you can use a rotation tag in your xml file to rotate your `TextView`.