# Android rotate animation and translate animation not working together

Tags: android, android-animation

I am developing two different animations as shown below.

[image]

The first animation I was able to develop using Object animator and FrameLayout. Basically, I created the two rectangles and the candlesticks inside a gravity-centered frame layout. When made to start the animation, I used the object animator to move them on either side and return to the initial position.

My second animation is the issue point here. In this animation, the rectangles will go on a circular path from their initial point and return back to their initial point. During this course, the candles need to move in sync with the rectangle giving a spring effect (or) kind of a sliced rectangle.
My initial idea was to re-use the first animation and just as the first animation runs, I would run a rotate animation on the frameLayout view.
But that doesn't seem to work wherein rotation works but the translation doesn't.

Can someone say if I have taken the right approach or should I use some other way to achieve this?

Adding the code that I have tried, but didn't work.

```
    Animation anim = new RotateAnimation(0.0f, 360.0f, pivotX, pivotY);
    anim.setDuration(500);
    anim.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
            for(View view : mCandleSticks) {
                ObjectAnimator anim1 = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view, "translationX", view.getX(), targetPos, view.getX());
                anim1.setDuration(500);//set duration
                anim1.start();//start animation
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {

        }
    });
    frameLayout.startAnimation(anim);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show some a snippet of code? The explanation is helpful but the actual code would allow us to understand it better and maybe even find a problem, if any.

Comment: @THEPATEL..  I have added code that I have tried.

Comment: @user3022690 go for this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6979792/androidtranslation-and-rotation-animation-simultaneously, it helps you